# Is it good for SEO when I use the same keywords in many pages on a site?

Tags: seo, keywords, title, canonical-url

On my website I have photo wallpapers. I want to optimize this page for search engines. There is one main page where all of this photos are listed. On this main page I use keywords like "photo", "free photo", and "wallpaper" in the title, h1, descriptions, and text.

When user clicks on some photo, it opens in second page with the same keywords. I'm not sure if it is good for rankings when I use the same keywords on other pages.

On this second page, should I use meta tag with rel='canonical' for better SEO?

Comment: Hard to rank pages with one photo and a little bit of text. In fact many of this types of sites have been slammed by Google for basically offering low content and user value. Nothing more frustrating to have to go to a page to view one image and then repeat this process over and over. User experience trumps all SEO in the long run. Pages will lots of related images to one another will rank better long term because people will stay on the page longer, more likely to link to it and so on...

Comment: Thank you for your comment... Yes, I'm afraid of this. But, what can I do for SEO, if I offer for people free image with free downloading. This kind of webpages also needs SEO. I think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very good for search engine rankings to use keywords on multiple pages.    This is different from a few years ago when the best SEO was to build one page that specifically targeted every phrase for which you wanted to rank.

Today, Google wants to direct visitors to sites that thoroughly cover all aspects of a topic.  One way to demonstrate this is to have lots of pages about a topic.

That being said, you don't want to have *exactly* the same title on any two of your pages.  Pages should be titled in such a way that they accurately reflect what the page is about.  So your pages should have titles like:

- Homepage: Thousands of free wallpapers
- Wallpaper of goats eating cans
- Wallpaper of a ocean sunset
- Wallpaper of a man on a unicycle

Unless two of your pages have substantially the same content (for example two pages with the same wallpaper image but at different resolutions), you should not use a rel canonical meta tag.

Comment: So if I have very similar photos... Is it good for SEO, if I use title like "Photo #0001" "Photo #0002"... ?

Comment: Numbers in titles are almost never good for SEO.  Users don't like to click on them, they are not friendly.  Use descriptive text instead.

Comment: Yep, describe the picture.... This is what ALT tag is for. Pretend your telling a blind audience what is the image about.. So if a goat is drinking milk... alt="Goat Drinking Milk" if you then have 2 similar pictures you then vary it alt="Goat Drinking Milk near a stack of hay" Alt="Goat Drinking milk in the barn" etc. Only use numbers when you have near identical images.

Comment: Use descriptive file names too. `goat-drinks-milk.jpg` with alt text of "Small goat drinking milk" is the best for SEO (a congruent page title, caption and perhaps a description are smart too). If you need other details in the file name so be it: `goat-drinks-milk-001-600x600-2013.opt.jpg` would be fine as well.

Comment: I guess you should focus on the keywords which are more relevant to the web page rather than stuffing unrelated keywords because it was in your home page.